# Access reactive-table row data in template/helper?

Tags: meteor

For [Tabular:](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular#template-cells)

> “In your template and helpers, `this` is set to the document for the
>   current row”

Is there an equivalent of this for [reactive-table](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table)? I need to access a rows data in my template/helper but am just struggling to find a way to access it, with tabular it was as easy as using `this.`

I'm using a template for a column called "Status" and in this there are different types of labels, depending on what the row data returns it will be a different type of label. The code below works for Tabular but I'm not really sure how to make this work for reactive-table?

Example.html

```
<template name="ApplicationStatus">
  <div class="row">
      {{#if statusPending}}
        <label class="label label-warning label-xs">"Pending</label>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if statusConnected}}
        <label class="label label-primary label-xs">Connected</label>
      {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Example.js

```
Template.ApplicationStatus.helpers({
  statusPending: function() {
    if (this.applications.app_status === 'Pending')
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  },
  statusConnected: function() {
    if (this.applications.app_status === 'Connected')
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
});
```

I am currently adding it to my reactive-table by doing this:

```
{ tmpl: Template.ApplicationStatus, label: 'Status' }
```

Any info is greatly appreciated or if there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve I would love to hear that as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL; DR

Try `Template.instance().data` instead of `this`.

### Little explanation

I am not shure what happenes when you miss `key` definition, but accoriding to [docs](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#templates):

> You can specify a template to use to render cells in a column, by
>   adding tmpl to the field options.
>
> ```
> { fields: [
>     { key: 'name', label: 'Name', tmpl: Template.nameTmpl },
>     { key: 'location', label: 'Location', tmpl: Template.locationTmpl }
> ] }
> ```
>
> The template's context will be the full object, so it will have access
>   to all fields.

So inside helpers and event handlers you can get access to full row object via `Template.instance().data`.